# How to compare current date with selected date in android with java

Tags: android

I am taking current date using the code like below

```
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();
java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);
```

And I am selecting date using

```
CalendarView cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)

String s = +year + " : " + (month + 1) + " : " +dayOfMonth ;
```

and passing  it on next activity as--

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sec.class);
in.putExtra("TextBox", s.toString());
startActivity(in);
```

I want to check here if user selected previous date from current date 
then give a message and don't go on next activity.

Answer (score 26):

**Use SimpleDateFormat:**

If your date is in ***31/12/2014*** format.

```
String my_date = "31/12/2014"
```

Then you need to convert it into **SimpleDateFormat**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(my_date);
if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
    your_date_is_outdated = true;
}
else{
    your_date_is_outdated = false;
}
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(my_date);
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {
    your_date_is_outdated = true;
}
else{
    your_date_is_outdated = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the modern answer.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**To take the current date**

```
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(currentDate);
```

When I ran this code just now, the output was:

> 2020-01-05

**To get selected date in your date picker**

```
    int year = 2019;
    int month = Calendar.DECEMBER; // but don’t use `Calendar`
    int dayOfMonth = 30;

    LocalDate selectedDate = LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);

    System.out.println(selectedDate);
```

> 2019-12-30

Your date picker is using the same insane month numbering that the poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar` class is using. Only for this reason, in an attempt to produce readable code, I am using a constant from that class to initialize `month`. In your date picker you are getting the number given to you, so you have no reason to use `Calendar`. So don’t.

And for the same reason, just as in your own code I am adding 1 to `month` to get the correct month number (e.g., 12 for December).

**Is the date in the past?**

```
    if (selectedDate.isBefore(currentDate)) {
        System.out.println("" + selectedDate + " is in the past; not going to next activity");
    } else {
        System.out.println("" + selectedDate + " is OK; going to next activity");
    }
```

> 2019-12-30 is in the past; not going to next activity

**Converting to String and back**

If you need to convert your selected date to a string in order to pass it through the `Intent` (I don’t know whether this is a requirement), use the `toString` and `parse` methods of `LocalDate`:

```
    String dateAsString = selectedDate.toString();
    LocalDate recreatedLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString);
    System.out.println(recreatedLocalDate);
```

> 2019-12-30

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

1. Create a date object using date formator.
2. Compare date (There many way out to compare dates and one is mentioned here)
3. Open intent or make toast as you said message.

   ```
   CalendarView cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
       String s =  (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year;
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
       Date dateSource = null;
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       Date sysDate = cal.getTime();

       try {
           dateSource = sdf.parse(s);
           if(dateSource.compareTo(sysDate)>0){
               Toast.makeToast("Selected worng date",Toast.SHOW_LONG).show();
           }else{
               Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sec.class);
               in.putExtra("TextBox", s.toString());
               startActivity(in);
           }
       }
       catch (ParseException e) {
           Loger.log("Parse Exception " + e);
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
   }
   ```

**Edit**

1. You need a view xml having the calender defined in it. It can be a fragment or activity view xml file
2. Inflate the view in your Activity or fragment class.

> View _rootView = inflater.inflate({your layout file},container, false);

3. Get the respective control java object from the xml like

> cal = (CalendarView)_rootView.findViewById(R.id.calViewId);

4. Now call event listener on this cal object.

Comment: What is exception then as code above will work or throw exception. If not both then issue is with your calendar control or some thing else

Comment: I have added some more details in answer. Thats what I can help right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this lines of code, this may help. Cheers!!!

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(enteredDate);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > date.getTime()) {
            //Entered date is backdated from current date
        } else {
            //Entered date is updated from current date
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is basically like [second snippet here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759484/7404943), but wrapped in try-catch block

Comment: Close enough, I found this is more convenient way. I just shared my block of codes.